# Passing data from Client to Server

Tags: javascript, express, fetch

In my code I want to pass an id from client to server.
I am trying to use fetch setting the Content-Type to Application/json but it looks like we have some problems (I analized the request and it doesn't create the body). 
Is there a simply way to pass data from client to server?

```
{#each accounts}}
    <form action="/users/chat" method="POST">
      <div class="form-group">
        <p>{{@index}}</p>
        <label for="name" value={{username}}>{{username}}</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">{{email}}</label>
      </div>
      <button class="myButton" id="{{@index}}">chat</button>
      </form>

    {{else}}
    <p>No account</p>
    {{/each}}


<script>

  const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('myButton');
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click',  function(e) {
      let ident=this.id;
      console.log(ident);
      console.log('button was clicked');
   fetch("/myurl",{
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({id : ident})
})    
}



</script>
```

Comment: Hi! It seems to work. Do you get any errors? Btw, if you are only interested in sending data to the server, you shouldn't need the `Accept` header.

Comment: I don't get any error, but on the server side if I try to print the body of the request i have a blank body. One more think that I noticed is that the content-type of my request get changed from Application/Json to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. I have to get also datas from the server, that's why I need accept :)

Comment: Have you checked DevTools on the client? I made a similar request with Chrome DevTools and it showed me the right headers and the right body. Maybe it's a server side issue.

Comment: That's what I'm doing on the server side   router.get('/chat', ensureAuthenticated, (req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    res.render('chat');
})

Comment: could you post your server code?

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar it is in the answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code of the server:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const db = require('../config/database');
const Account = require('../models/Account');
const chat = require('../models/chat');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Op = Sequelize.Op;
var passport = require('passport');
LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const {ensureAuthenticated}=require('../config/auth');
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.json());

//Socket
const PORTS = process.env.PORT || 7001;
var client = require('socket.io').listen((PORTS, console.log`SOCKET started on port ${PORTS}`)).sockets;

var password;
var username;
var accounts;

//Register
router.get('/register', function(req,res){
    res.render('register');
});

//CHAT
router.get('/chat', ensureAuthenticated, (req,res)=>{
    console.log(request.body.user.id);
    res.render('chat');
});
    module.exports=router;
```

Answer (score 0):

Having checked carefully, this line here in your request from client is the cause `fetch("/myurl",{ ...`

If you see the guide at [`MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), the usage is `fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')`. `Fetch API` expects complete [`url/uri`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) along with the protocol (`http, https`) etc.

So your request should be like:

`fetch("http://yourdomain.com", { ...`